# Where can I find up-to-date information about roadblocks and strikes in Peru and Bolivia?

Tags: online-resources, transportation, peru, south-america, bolivia

I need to travel from Cusco, Peru to La Paz, Bolivia next month but people in both countries have a habit of blocking roads quite frequently.

Every now and then I see news articles in the regular media about certain strikes still going strong (like right now between Cusco and La Paz...) but I was wondering if there is something like a web site somewhere that has up-to-date information about whole regions / countries / continents.

Comment: I think in all countries are different ways to track down the traffic.

Comment: If this is not the right place to ask, no problem, but I would appreciate an explanation of the downvote.

Comment: That's not me..

Comment: I think this is a great question. I wish I had answers to this when I started travelling in Mexico years ago where it used to be common in some areas but wasn't any longer on my last visit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

G Adventures provide a lot of South American tours.  They also monitor any safety updates in that region for their travellers.  Here's a timeline of updates and safety info within the last few months:

http://www.gadventures.com/safety-updates/

Comment: Nice, that's pretty much what I was looking for!

Answer (score 6):

I used Wikitravel.  Being a wiki, quite often people will enter info about strikes - I found the road between Uyuni and La Paz was closed two weeks before and two weeks after I went through, and I got that via Wikitravel.

Note that from Cusco, you will most likely travel to [Puno](http://www.marksmayo.com/2011/04/10/lake-titicaca-puno-peru-and-the-search-for-cuy-begins/) first.  It's a small, mostly dull town, but from there you have two travel options.  The quick bus route south to La Paz (see [link](http://www.marksmayo.com/2011/04/10/lake-titicaca-puno-peru-and-the-search-for-cuy-begins/)) or you can go via Copacobana, where you and the bus take separate ferrie across.  If you have time, that route sounds quite interesting and fun.

The point, however, is that there are two routes, so even if one gets blocked, there's a chance you'll have another way :)  If in doubt, follow the locals, they'll be used to it!

Comment: Thanks, that looks interesting although I don´t see a news section or something like that. Are you talking about a specific page or the Peru / Bolivia pages in general?

Comment: Generally I'd look up the towns. So for example http://wikitravel.org/en/Puno - has an important update about the current strikes right at the top.